# Htaccess mod_rewrite directory trouble

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im having trouble with my clean urls.

It works just fine on index.php, but on any other link it adds a folder to the root. For example if im on localhost/test/link/ it gets the css from link/css/main.css.

I guess i have to set a root directory folder, but since im developing locally it would be a pain to constantly change it between localhost and .com domains. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: have you tried with virtual host on your local system ?

Comment: First time i hear about it, what is it?

Comment: you can create virtual domain on local system for each of your projects. eg: `hustlerinc.xyx.local`. Whatever the software your using xampp/wamp you can create vhost easily. do some google you will find the way to create vhost.

Comment: Thanks, Will look it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this HTML tag in head of all pages: (your website root address)

```
<base href="http://localhost/">
```

Comment: if you use this code, all of css, relative links, images & ... load based on http://localhost/